# bootstrap modal doesn't work after make the layout of its razor container to null

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 MVC project. I want to create or edit data in a modal popup after the user clicks on its related button. I have implemented my requirements exactly the same as in the https://www.codaffection.com/asp-net-core-article/jquery-ajax-crud-in-asp-net-core-mvc/ website. Now when I click add button in the index razor it shows a modal containing all the fields and after clicking save button on it, it saves my entered data in the fields to the DB and show it in the table in index view. Also for editing, it works correct. The strategy for implementation is I put an empty modal code in _Layout and in Index razor view when the user for instance clicks on 'Add' or 'Edit' button, the related function in site.js is called and and that function calls the modal in _Layout and a modal containg AddOrEdit razor view (The razor shows on the modal) whill pop up to the user. However my problem is the displayed modal shows the layout style like the footer and header that are repeated in all website pages. For not showing them in modal I added the following code in AddOrEdit razor view:

```
@{
        Layout = null;
    }
```

but after adding this line in razor view, the "add" and "edit "buttons in index view for showing modal doesn't work at all and the don't show a modal.

Here is my code in _Layout. All other implemented code are the same as in the mentioned website.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="~/css/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap-v4-rtl-master/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/iransans.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
        <style>
           
    
            .my-nav-li:hover {
                background-color: rgb(50, 149, 155);
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="vertical-nav bg-dark text-white" id="sidebar">
            <div class=" mb-4 bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow topheader text-center">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <a class="navbar-brand m-0 col-12 row align-items-center p-3">
                        @*<partial>@Html.("_partialOne", "Home")</partial>*@
                        <img src="~/images/manucipality logo.png" style="width: 3rem;height: 3rem;margin-left:1rem;" />
                        <h6 style="color:white;display:inline-block;">Dashboard</h6>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
    
                <ul class="nav pr-1">
    
                    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center col-12 my-nav-li py-2" id="main_layout">
                        <span class="bi bi-circle-fill"></span>
                        <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-house" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 13.5V7h1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7h1v6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5zm11-11V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Main Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center col-12 my-nav-li py-2" id="request_layout">
                        <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-check" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.854 6.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 8.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 1h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zm0 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H4z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Applicants" asp-action="Index">requests</a>
                        <span class="bi bi-circle-fill"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center col-12 my-nav-li py-2" id="user_layout">
    
                        <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-people float-right" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 14s1 0 1-1-1-4-5-4-5 3-5 4 1 1 1 1h8zm-7.995-.944v-.002.002zM7.022 13h7.956a.274.274 0 0 0 .014-.002l.008-.002c-.002-.264-.167-1.03-.76-1.72C13.688 10.629 12.718 10 11 10c-1.717 0-2.687.63-3.24 1.276-.593.69-.759 1.457-.76 1.72a1.05 1.05 0 0 0 .022.004zm7.973.056v-.002.002zM11 7a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4zm3-2a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0zM6.936 9.28a5.88 5.88 0 0 0-1.23-.247A7.35 7.35 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4 0 .667.333 1 1 1h4.216A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.01.377-2.042 1.09-2.904.243-.294.526-.569.846-.816zM4.92 10c-1.668.02-2.615.64-3.16 1.276C1.163 11.97 1 12.739 1 13h3c0-1.045.323-2.086.92-3zM1.5 5.5a3 3 0 1 1 6 0 3 3 0 0 1-6 0zm3-2a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4z"></path>
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Applicants" asp-action="Index">reports</a>
                    </li>
    
    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="page-content p-0 col-12" id="content">
            <header style="border-right:1px solid #716f6f;">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light border-bottom box-shadow p-0 topheader" style="background-color:#343a40">
                    <div class="row col-sm-12 col-6 m-0 p-0 align-items-center" style="background-color:#343a40">
                        <span class="oi oi-menu mr-4 p-0 m-1" id="sidebarCollapse" style="color:#343a40;"></span>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-7 p-0">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav p-0 mr-3">
                                <li class="nav-item active my-nav-li">
                                    <a href="Home" class="nav-link" style="color:white">My Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item my-nav-li">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="color:white">settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    
                        @*<div class="container">
                                &copy; 2020 - WastePanel - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                            </div>*@
    
                        <div class="d-flex row  align-left align-items-center col-10 col-sm-4 m-0 pl-2 pr-0 h-6">
                           
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-8 p-0 mb-3 text-left">
                               
                                <div class="user-name-size" style="display: inline-block;position: relative;left: 1rem;top: 0.2rem;">@await Component.InvokeAsync("MySharedData")</div>
    
                                <button class="btn btn-light" style="display: inline-block; height: 1.7rem; width: 3rem;">
                                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" style="text-decoration:none; bottom: 0.25rem;
    position: relative;color:black;font-size: 0.8rem;left: 0.25rem;bottom: 0.45rem;">exit</a>
                                </button>
    
                            </div>
    
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
    
            
            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="form-modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
    
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0" style="background-color: #eeeaea;">
                <main role="main" class="" style="background-color: white;">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
    
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" style="position:absolute; height: 0;">
                    <p style="margin-bottom: 4rem;">All rights reserved</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/css/persian-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
            <script src="~/js/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.js"></script>
           
    
            @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false);
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is AddOrEdit code:

```
@model Gate
@*@{
        Layout = null;
    }*@

<body>
    <head>
        <link href="~/contents/Edit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    


    <hr />

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            $(".statesSelect").select2({
                language: "fa"
            });

        });
    </script>


    <div class="row sub3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="AddOrEdit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label mylabel">name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

here is the Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CSDDashboard.Models.Gate>

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<div id="view-all">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ViewAll", Model)
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

And here is _ViewAll.cshtml like in the website

```
@model Gate>
<head>
    <link href="~/css/DataTable/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/contents/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>



<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({

          
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="main">
    <div class="sub sub2 mt-3 mr-2 border-primary">
        <div class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            @*<a asp-action="Create" class="a-ijaad">new record</a>*@
            <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Gates",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','new')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> new gate</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div id="tablecontainer" class="my-5 col-sm-12 p-4">
    <table id="myDummyTable" class="table m-table mytable table-striped table-bordered mb-4">
        <thead>
            <tr id="headerrow">
                <th>
                    name
                </th>
               
                <th>
                    operations
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                   
                    <td>
                        
                        <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Gates",new {id=item.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)','edit')" class="btn btn-info text-white"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> edit</a>|
                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

I appreciate if anyone could solve my problem.

Comment: Removing layout in AddOrEdit.cshtml will lead to missing css, but where do you reference AddOrEdit, in modal? Is modal a partial view? Last, you can change AddOrEdit to a partial view.

Comment: How can I make it as Partial view?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes after adding some css from Layout into AddOrEdit, it works fine.

Comment: You can create a separate layout for AddOrEdit.